# How to use a specific chapter heading

Tags: sectioning

What packages/commands can I use to create headings like this one:

[image]

Comment: There's a package that does it. But it's one of the ugliest chapter headings I've ever seen. There are some worse than this in that package.

Comment: titlesec package contains examples similar to this one (see p.19 of its manual)

Comment: That is the heading used in the `fncychap` package manual, which is the package @egreg was referring to.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you can use the package `fncychap` for this. I don't know this package at all so maybe I am not referring to the right style, but you can have a look on the documentation for further styles.

The style I think you are looking for is calles "Lenny":

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```